# Short query from GROUP BY/COUNT with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I generated this query with for cicle in php (replaced columns):

```
select
 count(`a`) as `countAdd`, `a` as `asd`
 from `question`
 where
 (
 (`a` = 1 and ((`v` is not null and `b` not in (1,2)) or (`v` is null and `b` not in (6,7)))
 or
 (`a` = 2 and ((`v` is not null and `b` not in (2,3)) or (`v` is null and `b` not in (8,9)))
 or
 (`a` = 3 and ((`v` is not null and `b` not in (4,5)) or (`v` is null and `b` not in (8,4)))
 or
 (`a` = 4 and ((`v` is not null and `b` not in (4,9)) or (`v` is null and `b` not in (6,2)))
 or
 (`a` = 5 and ((`v` is not null and `b` not in (2,6)) or (`v` is null and `b` not in (3,4)))
 )
 and `deleted_at` is null group by `addresseeId`
```

in php

```
foreach ($a as $v)
    $query .= '(`a` = ? and ((`b` is not null and `c` not in (?)) or (`a` is null `b` not in (?)))';
```

How can I avoid queries this long when I'm working with bigger data?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Could you please give us "the logic" of your values in queries to understand how to loop it ? everything looks like random and unpredictable...

Comment: Knowing why you wrote the query like that in the first place would be helpful. As a generic answer to your almost unanswerable question, you can avoid writing overly-complicated queries by structuring your database differently. There's a whole category of computer science dedicated to database design. Here's one of a whole lot of resources on the subject. http://opensourceforu.com/2011/05/a-simple-guide-to-database-design-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not so much non-technical background on this question, I will give you general suggestion.

Sometimes it makes sense to get all data you need and then kinda sort it out in php itself. The query you're building could become really big with bigger data so I will avoid building query in a loop.

Another possible solution to your problem could be redesigning your database. If you notice at some point, that your queries are getting inappropriate big, so there is probably some problems in your database design. Check [this link](http://opensourceforu.com/2011/05/a-simple-guide-to-database-design-in-mysql/) for database design (Thanks @castis)